# I,m very new to android and Java. I want to get a string array from one class to another class

Tags: java, android, arrays

Here the second class is called through a function go(). In this function string array 'givenWrds' is not accessible (I don't know why)

General idea : It is a code fragment of memory game in which user is provided with certain words then after few seconds user needs to retype that words.here 'givenWrds' is the array of randomly selected words.I want to get this array to another java activity for comparing against user entered words.

---

### Here is my code:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class wordlist extends AppCompatActivity {
    void go() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, timeup.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public TextView text;
    public TextView countDownText;
    private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wordlist);

        Intent intent = getIntent(); // gets the previously created intent
        int level = intent.getIntExtra("level_pass", 0);
        int numWrds = intent.getIntExtra("numWrds_pass", 0);
        int pts = intent.getIntExtra("pts_pass", 0);
        int sec = intent.getIntExtra("sec_pass", 0);
        int startTime = (sec + 1) * 1000;
        int interval = 1 * 1000;

        countDownText = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.countDown);
        countDownTimer = new wordlist.MyCountDownTimer(startTime, interval);
        countDownText.setText(countDownText.getText() + String.valueOf(startTime / 1000));
        countDownTimer.start();

        String[] word = {"clear", "race", "belong",. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .,
        "allow", "witty", "selective", "small", "health"};

        String[] givenWrds = new String[numWrds];

        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < numWrds; ++i) {
            int randomNum = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 999 + 1);
            if (!(Arrays.asList(givenWrds).contains(word[randomNum])))
                givenWrds[i] = word[randomNum];
        }
        String display = " ";
        for (i = 0; i < numWrds; ++i) {
            display += givenWrds[i];
            display += "\n";
        }
        text = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.wordsDisplay);
        text.setText(display);
    }

    public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {
        public MyCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval) {
            super(startTime, interval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            go();

        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            countDownText.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry,it is not accessible inside go method (check the code carefully)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare the array as class variable, so that you can accessible in other methods,

```
public class wordlist extends AppCompatActivity {
    String[] givenWrds = null;

    void go() {
        if(givenWrds ==null) {
            return;
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, timeup.class);
        intent.putExtra("value", givenWrds);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      //... change String[] givenWrds = new String[numWrds]; to below like
      givenWrds = new String[numWrds];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From Source Class:

```
String[] arr = new String[]{"hii","hello"};
    Intent intent  =  new Intent(this,DestinationClass.class);
    intent.putExtra("string_array",arr);
    startActivity(intent);
```

In Destination Class:-

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout);
  String[] arr =   getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("string_array");
}
```